# iOS AppStore App Preview and iMovie

Tags: ios, app-store

Just trying to create an app preview for the iOS AppStore and failing miserably. Managed to capture the video and Spielberg would be impressed with my edit (in iMovie) - but then iTunes Connect requires the iPad (landscape) preview video to be 1200x900 - which is not supported by iMovie. Anyone know how this should be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of September 2014, Apple has updated iMovie so that if you select "New App Preview" and put Quicktime recorded footage from an iPad, it will be 900 x 1200 or 1200 x 900.

Answer (score 4):

Do you still have iMovie 9 on your Mac? Even if you update, it still lives on your system and typing "imovie 9" in Spotlight should bring it up. For iPad previews iMovie 9 is a lot better since you can make 4:3 videos and then export them in 1200x900.

To export in iMovie 9, use the option to "Export from Quicktime" which opens a prompt that gives you much more control over the export. 1200x900 isn't a selectable option from any drop down, but this export from quicktime option lets you input whatever custom resolution you want. As long as the source files are 1200x900 or higher there should be no quality degradation.

If you don't have iMovie 9 as an option then you'll have to use Final Cut or some other program.

Comment: Great tip! Couldn't try with iMovie 9 but this worked with iMovie 8.

Answer (score 0):

iMovie doesn't support custom canvas sizes - so you need to use Final Cut Pro (there's a 30 day trial) or something like Camtasia.